# How to sum a row from two dataframe that has the row with certain same value in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Expected output is a dataframe:

| Dates | Total Revenue |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-11-01 | 59946202 |
| 2019-11-02 | 95429717 |
| 2019-11-03 | 89662309 |
| ... | ... |
| 2020-03-31 | 6687349 |

Dataframe 1:

[image]

Dataframe 2:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Change the Dates as the "Index" of the DataFrame, it will then automatically perform data alignment in arithmetic calculation.

Comment: Ive change the date to index like this:
`new1 = rev_grup_rp.set_index('Date')
new2 = rev_grup_usd_converted.set_index('Date')`
So, what to do next?

Comment: @adlofMerlin `new1['col'] + new2['col']`.

Comment: Okay thanks, so, after that, how to change index to be a column again?

Comment: by using `reset_index()`

Comment: but when i save to csv file, why there is only one column (only revenue) without date?

Comment: Sorry, i got it, i did some syntax problem, thanks for your help 

Answer (score 0):

Merge the different dataframe and then use concat function for your need.
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/merging.html
Eexample
Frames = [df1, df2]
Result = pd.concat(Frames)